# how to fix my implementation of Auto-complete feature using Trie Tree?

Tags: c++

Hi so i've been trying to implement Auto-complete/suggestion using trie tree
but the suggestion part only suggests 1 or 2 first similar words to it and i can't find out what causing this.

This is my Trie structre

```
 struct TrieNode {
        struct TrieNode* children[ALPHABET_SIZE];

        bool isEndOfWord;
};


struct TrieNode* getNode(void) {
       struct TrieNode* pNode = new TrieNode;

       pNode->isEndOfWord = false;

       for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
            pNode->children[i] = NULL;

       return pNode;
}

bool isLeafNode(struct TrieNode* root) { return root->isEndOfWord != false; }
```

and this is the suggestion/Auto-complete part

```
void suggestionsRec(struct TrieNode* root, string currPrefix) {
     if (root->isEndOfWord) {
         cout << currPrefix;
         cout << endl;
     }

     if (isLeafNode(root))
         return;

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (root->children[i])
        {
            currPrefix.push_back(97 + i);
            suggestionsRec(root->children[i], currPrefix);
            currPrefix.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

int spellchecker(TrieNode* root, const string query) {
    struct TrieNode* pCrawl = root;
    int level;
    int n = query.length();

    for (level = 0; level < n; level++) {
         int index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(query[level]);
         if (!pCrawl->children[index])
             return 0;
         pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
    }

    bool isWord = (pCrawl->isEndOfWord == true);
    bool isLast = isLeafNode(pCrawl);

    if (isWord && isLast) {
        cout << query << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (!isLast) {
        string prefix = query;
        suggestionsRec(pCrawl, prefix);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

for example when i try words like : [ the , there , these ] and input is "t" all it suggests is "the" .

this is the whole code https://pastebin.com/VPd94rny

also any suggestion to improve my code is much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This community is for **specific** programming questions, not a code review. Please ask a **question** about some part of your program that you have struggles with / compilation errors.

Comment: You stop recursion once you reach a node marked `isEndOfWord`. But this node may nevertheless have children, if the word it represents is a prefix of another word. Which is exactly the case with `the` and `there`